# "Il pensait que le bien était une essence" (Utilisation de "essence")

Tags: expressions

Imaginez une discussion entre deux personnes, dont la première croit que l'essence du bien est incorruptible (qu'il y a une "essence du bien") alors que la seconde pense que le bien n'existe pas sous sa forme pure parce qu'il est toujours associé à une recherche d'intérêt personnel (qu'il n'y a donc pas "d'essence du bien").

Puis-je dire de la première que :

> Elle croit que le bien est une essence

L'idée derrière est de montrer qu'elle croit que le bien existe, comme une particule, indivisible, incorruptible, qu'on pourrait extraire sous forme d'essence (qu'on pourrait extraire ce qui fait sa nature, son essence même). On obtiendrait donc du bien pur, à 100%.

j'ai un doute sur l'usage du mot "essence" dans cette tournure, je connais la tournure "l'essence du bien", mais ce n'est pas ce que je cherche à dire ici. Je ne cherche pas non plus a dire que "le bien *a* une essence", mais que le bien *est* (ou n'est pas) fait d'une nature, *d'une essence*. (Comme si le bien était -ou pas- en chimie une particule élémentaire)

Ma phrase est elle correcte dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 2):

Cette phrase me paraît *correcte*,

Malgré certaines confusions entre les formes famillières ou synonymes du mot "essence" qui peuvent survenir rarement suivant la compréhension du texte.

Pour cela, mieux vaut coordonner le mot avec le thème du texte.

Answer (score 2):

Dans "l'essence du bien" le mot "essence" signifie le principe, le contenu fondamental du bien.

Le bien n'est donc pas une essence. Au mieux, on pourrait dire qu'il a une essence d'un type ou d'un autre.

Par analogie, ce n'est pas parce qu'on parle de la "composition du produit" que l'on dira que le produit est une composition.

Comment: Ton analogie est super ! "On pourrait dire qu'il a une essence d'un type ou d'un autre", oui d'accord, mais ça ne règle pas le problème : comment puis je dire, que le "type" pour le bien, c'est... le bien. Comment dire que le produit est fait d'une composition bien spécifique, de particule élémentaire —de bien, ou de mal— qu'on pourrait isoler ? Peut-être qu'il serait plus facile et moins confusant de tourner le dialogue sous l'angle de particules opposées, qui se repoussent.

Answer (score 1):

Ta phrase me paraît tout à fait correcte.
Si cela te chiffonne, ne pourrais-tu pas formuler ta phrase en employant "par essence" ?

Comment: merci, mais il me semble que "par essence" ne permet pas de dire qu'il s'agit d'une substance, d'une particule en soit (qu'il y a des particules/une essence de bien, et d'autres particules/une essence fondamentalement différentes de mal)

Answer (score 0):

La phrase est correcte, mais incomplète pour la discussion des deux personnes : le bien est un valeur morale, donc liée à l'imagination, lui donner une *essence*, c'est lui donner une *substance* intangible.

Tout contradicteur pourra ergoter sur l'acception de ce mot, pour lever les ambiguïtés de votre phrase, on peut préciser le type d'*essence* :

> Elle croit que le bien est une essence *spirituelle*.

... ou encore, on peut passer de la croyance à la recherche d'arguments philosophiques :

> Elle croit que le bien est *par essence*<sup>*1*</sup> spirituel.

---

<sup>*Par sa nature même - Le Robert*</sup>